# nx jest cannot find module `./.config/babel.config`

Tags: jestjs, babeljs, ts-jest, monorepo

I have an `app` inside my [nx](https://nx.dev) project, which uses [array-move](https://www.npmjs.com/package/array-move).

When writing a test for this app, jest crashes with:

```bash
    Details:

    .../node_modules/array-move/index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){export function arrayMoveMutable(array, fromIndex, toIndex) {
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

#### Updating the jest configuration

Therefore, I've modified the jest config like this:

```js
+ // Add modules to transform
+ const esModules = ['array-move'].join('|')
  
  module.exports = {
    displayName: 'project',
    preset: '../../jest.preset.js',
+   transformIgnorePatterns: [`node_modules/(?!${esModules})/`],
    transform: {
      '^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)': '@nrwl/react/plugins/jest',
      '^.+\\.[tj]sx?$': 'babel-jest',
    },
    moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx'],
    coverageDirectory: '../../coverage/apps/project,
    collectCoverageFrom: [
      '**/*.{ts,js,jsx,tsx,mjs}',
      '!.storybook/**/*',
      '!**/*.stories.tsx',
      '!src/environments/**/*',
    ],
  }
```

#### Follow up error (where I'm stuck at)

However, I ended up with the following error:

```bash
Cannot find module './.config/babel.config'
    Require stack:
    - .../node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/configuration.js
    - .../node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/index.js
    - .../node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js
    - .../node_modules/jest-snapshot/build/InlineSnapshots.js
    - .../node_modules/jest-snapshot/build/State.js
    - .../node_modules/jest-snapshot/build/index.js
    - .../node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js
    - .../node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js
    - .../node_modules/@jest/core/build/jest.js
    - .../node_modules/jest/build/jest.js
    - .../node_modules/@nrwl/jest/src/executors/jest/jest.impl.js
    - .../node_modules/nx/src/config/workspaces.js
    - .../node_modules/nx/src/command-line/run.js
    - .../node_modules/nx/bin/run-executor.js

    Require stack:
      .../node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/configuration.js
      .../node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/index.js
      .../node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js
      .../node_modules/jest-snapshot/build/InlineSnapshots.js
      .../node_modules/jest-snapshot/build/State.js
      .../node_modules/jest-snapshot/build/index.js
      .../node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js
      .../node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js
      .../node_modules/@jest/core/build/jest.js
      .../node_modules/jest/build/jest.js
      .../node_modules/@nrwl/jest/src/executors/jest/jest.impl.js
      .../node_modules/nx/src/config/workspaces.js
      .../node_modules/nx/src/command-line/run.js
      .../node_modules/nx/bin/run-executor.js

      at loadConfig (../../node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/configuration.js:172:5)
          at loadConfig.next (<anonymous>)
      at mergeExtendsChain (../../node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:387:45)
          at mergeExtendsChain.next (<anonymous>)
      at ../../node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:373:20
      at loadFileChain (../../node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:232:24)
          at loadFileChain.next (<anonymous>)
```

I have a `.babelrc` in the root of the nx app, and there is a `babel.config.json` in the project root.

Comment: I have the same problem now with Nx+jest, though a different lib, I have an import from @mui/x-data-grid and for the world I can't get it to not ignore it.
I think you may have an error in your transformIgnorePatterns though. In jest documentation https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#transformignorepatterns-arraystring they provide an example "/node_modules/(?!(foo|bar)/)" - they have the last "/" evaluated as part of the Negative Lookahead (?!(.....)/), while yours is after (?!...)/ - I can replicate your error if I write: transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules//']

Comment: @Slawoj Thanks for the input. I have found [a helpful comment on Github](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/812#issuecomment-1176989239). It seems to work, but I had to remove `"babelrcRoots": ["*"]` in the roots babel.config.json and add `@babel/preset-env` to the presets there. Will provide an answer once I'm sure the setup works.